# Landing Page as home page

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I know this may sound simple and over asked, but I searched and didn't found. I also asked on two other forums and they couldn't answer.

So here I go:

I have a joomla website (www.example.com) The home page is www.example.com/en, but I want to have a landing page directly on www.example.com. On this page will be a menu to redirect to the main site which is in 3 different languages (so a menu with 3 options). I already have my html and css page for the landing page-menu ready. I just need to know how to put it as the home page of my website.

I use GoDaddy, and there are many index.html, index.php, config.php, .htaccess, in the file manager. Do I just put my html and css files along with my images in the root folder? Or do I also need to redirect some url somewhere?

I hope I have been clear! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set **DirectoryIndex** in your **.htaccess** file.

```
DirectoryIndex intro.html index.php
```

This will make **intro.html** the default page that will be loaded and index.php as fallback.

Reference: [DirectoryIndex Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html).

Hope this helps

Comment: as I said, it worked and all, but now I am unable to enter my backend (joomla administration). Instead of it, the 404 page appear. So I guess the redirection in the .htaccess changed all that at the same time... What do you suggest?

Comment: I don't think that it could be a problem of `DirectoryIndex`. Please check my edit.

Answer (score -1):

Prepare a landing page with the menu as u wish and name index.php/ index.html as your choice. Replace the file on the server with this file.

Comment: This is Joomla, not some static HTML website.